# Powershell Script - Services Running eq OK or list Services Not Running

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-cmdlet

I have this script which checks multiple servers for particular services running.

I need assistance or pointers on how to get it to not pull back running / not running response. I need to get it to be "If all queried services are running = OK, if not list service not running"

Is this doable?

Script:

```
$Check1 = Get-service -Computername server1 -Name *service1* | ConvertTo-Html Name,Status -Fragment
$Check2 = Get-Service  -Computername server2 -name *service2* | ConvertTo-Html Name,Status  
$Check3 = Get-Service  -Computername server3 -name *service3* | ConvertTo-Html Name,Status
$Check4 = Get-Service -ComputerName UKVAULT01 -Name *service4* | ConvertTo-Html Name,Status
ConvertTo-HTML -Body "<b>Check1</b> $Check1 <br> <b>Check2</b> $Check2 <br> <b>Check3</b> $Check3<br> <b>Check4</b> $Check4" -Title "Service Checks" | Out-File c:\StatusReport.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Encapsulate the checks in a function like this:

```
function Check-Service{$server, $name) {
  $check = Get-Service $server -Name $name | ? { $_.Status -ne "Running" }
  if ( $check -eq $null ) { $check = "OK" }
  $check | ConvertTo-Html -Fragment
}

$Check1 = Check-Service server1 *service1*
$Check2 = Check-Service server2 *service2*
...
```

Comment: I hadnt got round to learning functions yet but this seriously cuts down the length of the lines involved will give it a while, thanks dude.

Comment: Is a function required for each server and its service?

Comment: Not unless you want to do different things for each server. You pass the names of the server and the service to the same function. See the bottom half of my code sample.

Comment: Different services to be check each time as different server run different apps.

Comment: That's why you pass server **and** service name.